# zlib gzclose: How to detect a successful file closure?

Tags: c++, c++11, zlib

I have used zlib to compress a file. All works well. After the operation is complete, I call `gzclose(file)` to flush and close the gzip file. According to the documentation, the `gzclose` returns an `int` which provides the success or failure of the `gzclose` operation. Since there can be many failure reasons, checking for each error code is not feasible for me. I opt to check for the success of the operation and handle error codes separately. I could not find the return code for successful `gzclose` in any of the documentation I referred.

[doc](https://nixdoc.net/man-pages/OpenBSD/man3/gzclose.3.html)

Comment: "On success, gzclose() shall return Z_OK. Otherwise, gzclose() shall return an error value as described below" first entry in google when searching "gzclose"
"#define Z_OK 0" first entry in google when searching "zlib.h"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zlib functions are documented in [zlib.h](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/zlib.h). You can also find zlib.h formatted a bit in the [zlib Manual](https://www.zlib.net/manual.html). In there you find:

> **`ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT gzclose OF((gzFile file));`**
>
> Flushes all pending output if necessary, closes the compressed file
> and deallocates the (de)compression state. Note that once file is
> closed, you cannot call `gzerror` with file, since its structures have
> been deallocated. `gzclose` must not be called more than once on the
> same file, just as `free` must not be called more than once on the same
> allocation. `gzclose` will return `Z_STREAM_ERROR` if file is not valid,
> `Z_ERRNO` on a file operation error, `Z_MEM_ERROR` if out of memory,
> `Z_BUF_ERROR` if the last read ended in the middle of a *gzip* stream, or
> `Z_OK` on success.